# Subscript a plus sign in latex

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I want to subscript a "+" or "-" sign. But it not working with this:

```
$$(\beta-\gamma)_{+}$$
```

It has not any error, But plus sign seeing inline instead of subscript.
any Idea?

Comment: assuming that is in math mode (which you need already for `\beta` )that will work. What error do you get?

Comment: Please always post complete documents that allow people to reproduce the error and give exact error messages from the log. "not working" is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I posted a edit.

Comment: Your edit does not help at all, you still haven't posted a document that would allow anyone to reproduce the problem, not have you said what error message you got. Also Answers should go in answer postings not by editing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\beta_{-}  \gamma_{+}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No Idea why. but after adding two empty $ $ sign after this expression this works :|

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but after I added two dollar sign with just a space between that, the problem solved. and plus sign became subscript. This is what I did:

```
$$(\beta-\gamma)_{+}$$
$ $
```